# Is it possible to input Chinese text into tk Text and Entry widgets with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter

I am working on a few GUI apps with tkinter that manipulate Chinese text inputted by the user. I have no problem displaying Chinese text in the app, nor do I have any problem manipulating that text when it is pasted into the app, but when I try to use a Chinese input method to type Chinese text into, e.g., Text or Entry widgets, it shows up as Latin characters instead. It seems like there should be a trivial solution to this problem (or maybe it just doesn't work), but I have spent a lot of time searching (in English and Chinese) for an answer, without finding anything definitive. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I student of Japanese that I know has no problem entering Kanji both in the Idle shell and tk Text widget with default settings.  OS is 64 bit Win 7, with 64 bit Python 3.4.

Comment: Strange...I am running Python 3.4 on 64 bit OS X, and can't type Chinese or Japanese in tk widgets or the idle shell - same thing I guess. This makes me think it might have something to do with the default OS X Chinese and Japanese input methods, since I have no problem getting the text to show up, I just can't type it...

Comment: both ubuntu and osx have the problem, windows not

Comment: I actually have had no problems entering Chinese text on Windows 8 or Ubuntu 14.04. For me the problem seems to be OS X specific. However, the version of tkinter I am running on Ubuntu is 8.6 - my version on OS X is 8.5, so that might be why it is working on Ubuntu for me. Maybe the problem will be solved on OS X too with 8.6, but I can't figure out how to update tkinter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this problem on Mac OS X 10.10 with Python 2.7.12 and Tcl/Tk 8.5.9.

And I fixed it by upgrading Tcl/Tk to 8.6.6 (someone stated that 8.5.18 may fix it also). It could be done by two ways:

1. If you use Homebrew to installed Python, use it to install Python again: "**brew install python --with-tcl-tk**" (may be you need to uninstall it first).
2. Or you may download the Python installation package from: http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads .

BTW, you are not able to input Chinese in the entry widget if you run the Python script from a "virtualenv" even this environment use the same verion of Python and Tcl/Tk.

Comment: Why can't you input Chinese into the entry widget from a virtualenv? Is there any way around this? It would help fix the problems I'm having here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813057/foriegn-keyboard-support-for-tkinter-snaps)