# Chinese text in Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, special-characters, cjk

is there anything I should do if I want to display Chinese characters in Tkinter in Python?
I want to diplay Chinese text on my labels. It seems like it works, kind of. It doesn't make the characters even - some of them are bold, some of them are not.

```
label = ttk.Label(text = "晚上好")
label.pack()
```

In this the "晚" appears bold, whereas "上好" does not. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Relevant [is-it-possible-to-input-chinese-text-into-tk-text-and-entry-widgets-with-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747976)

Comment: Try using a font which supports Chinese by `font` option.